# Change bgcolor of the text by giving condition PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change the background color of the text with a given condition. When the condition is met, the color will be changed. Here is the code I used But I got nothing in return. I tried to echo the color to see the color variable is working or not. Still, I got nothing.  What is the problem here? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
$dersevrakno =$row['Enstitu_KararNo'];
$bolum = $row['EABD_EvrakNo'];
$status = $bolum ? $bolum : NULL; //it says $bolum is empty = $status ( not sure its correct)
if(empty($dersevrakno) && $row['OgrenciNo'] == $user_studentid){  
 while ($status){
$color ="blue";
echo $color;  // to see $color is working or not 
}
?>   


   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["formgonderme"]; ?></td>    
    <td><?php echo $row["O_AdiSoyadi"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["OgrenciNo"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Derece"]; ?></td>

 <td width="4%"  style="background-color:<?php echo $color;?>">
  Bölüm Sekreterliği</td></tr>
   <?php

    } 
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that you have an extra double ***"*** quote in your style.

Updated code:

```
<td width="4%"  style="background-color:<?php echo $color;?>">
```

I can also recommend that you use a class so you can update different properties on the element with only it and you can used it on different tables and have the same consistent format.

Update to address if/while:

```
if(!empty($dersevrakno) && $row['OgrenciNo'] == $user_studentid && !empty($status)){  
     $color ="blue";
     echo $color;  // to see $color is working or not 
}else{
     // set a default color
     $color="white";
}
```

Comment: I believe that there is also something wrong the color variable since when I echo it. I got nothing

Comment: maybe you mean that when value is not empty on the if condition ? if so add **!** before to negate the empty() function **if( !empty($dersevrakno) && ...**

Comment: Also, since I want to do the conditional code in td tag. Should  I put the curly braces of that while($status] at the end of the code. When I did that, I even could not get the data.  I hope I make myself clear. Sorry  for my bad english

Comment: whats the purpose of the while($status) ?

Comment: First I tried to do it with if. But it did not work so I changed it with the while. It says that while the $bolum variable is empty, change the bg color.

Comment: First I changed the while with the if and move the if statement  before the   this : if(empty($dersevrakno) && $row['OgrenciNo'] == $user_studentid){    . Idk why but now it works

Comment: I saw that you got an accepted answer so you did fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have an `"` at the end.

The next point is, have a look on "DOM" elements and how to work with them. Probably it will open your mind of how to change active elements on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the order of the code and now it works

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $dersevrakno =$row['Enstitu_KararNo'];
    $bolum = $row['EABD_EvrakNo'];
    $status = $bolum ? $bolum : NULL;
    if ($status){
    $color ="red";

    }
 if(empty($dersevrakno) && $row['OgrenciNo'] == $user_studentid){

    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["formgonderme"]; ?></td>    
    <td><?php echo $row["O_AdiSoyadi"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["OgrenciNo"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Derece"]; ?></td>

    <td width="4%"  style="color:<?php echo $color;?>">Bölüm Sekreterliği</td>

    <?php
    }
}
  ?>
```